# onerror event using background: url()

Tags: html, css, image, background, onerror

Is there a way to show alternate image if source image is not found? I know to accomplish this is by doing something like below:

```
<img src="imagenotfound.gif" alt="Image not found" onError="this.src='imagefound.gif';" />
```

But how about if you are doing something like this, how can you catch if there is an error or if the image is not found?

```
<div style="background:url('myimage.gif')"></div>
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

In case `myimage.gif` isn't transparent, you could use multiple backgrounds:

```css
background: url('myimage.gif'), url('fallback.gif');
```

This way `fallback.gif` will only be visible if `myimage.gif` isn't available.

Note that `fallback.gif` may be downloaded even if `myimage.gif` is available.

---

Alternatively, even though not widely supported, CSS Images 3 introduces [the `image()` notation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#image-notation):

```css
background: image('myimage.gif', 'fallback.gif');
```

> Multiple [`<image-decl>s`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#image-decl-type) can be given separated by commas, in
>   which case the function represents the first image that's not an
>   [invalid image](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#invalid-image).

Comment: This is nitpicky, but a better name for the second image would be `imagenotfound.gif`, since it is displayed when the first image is not available

Comment: @oriol is there anyway to prevent the 404 messages in the console when the first image is not found

Comment: @SimonH Probably the console has some option to hide failed requests.

Comment: @jpussacq According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds), 94.58% browsers support multiple backgrounds.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately my client has IE8 :-(

Comment: @Oriol In my case .gif are transperant , any solution ?

Comment: @Ashish Then I think you will need JavaScript

Comment: CSS3 has not actually implemented image() yet. The reference is only to a Proposed Candidate Spec.

Comment: The published spec can be found here for this topic: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-image

Comment: image() has in fact been deferred to CSS 4 Images: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-images-4/#image-notation and is completely unsupported at the moment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_types_image_image

Comment: It's a damned shame because `image()` would be ideal. https://caniuse.com/#search=image()

Answer (score 6):

With background images, there is no event; you have check yourself.

[Make an (XML)HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX), and if you get a response with [an error status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) or no response at all (after timeout), use another image resource. This approach is limited by the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a dummy-image and use the onerror event from there ...

```
        $imageFoo = '
        <div id="' . $uniqueId . '"
             style="
                background-image: url(//foo.lall/image.png);
                -webkit-background-size: contain;
                -moz-background-size: contain;
                -o-background-size: contain;
                background-size: contain;
                background-position: center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
             "
        ></div>
        <!-- this is a helper, only needed because "background-image" did not fire a "onerror" event -->
        <img style="display: none;" 
             src="//foo.lall/image.png" 
             onerror="var fallbackImages = $(this).data(\'404-fallback\'); $(\'#' . $uniqueId . '\').css(\'background-image\', \'url(\' + fallbackImages + \')\');"
             data-404-fallback="//foo.lall/image_fallback.png"
        >
        ';
```