# Fix CSS url 404

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to catch CSS `background | background-image: url(..);` errors (e.g 404) with JavaScript and make corrections?

Only option I can think of right now is to loop over all elements in page, check  `background` and `background-image` property, if present, try to make corrections. This is undesirable fix as you can probably guess.

---

I've notices that if I use custom Image `src` setter, it seems that CSS `url` does make an Image in background and operate on that but even if I change its `src`, `url('images/example.jpg')` still stays the same and points to wrong path.

```js
const {get, set} = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Image.prototype, 'src');

Object.defineProperty(Image.prototype, 'src', {
  set(value) {
    // this gets called even for CSS url()
    return set.call(this, value);
  },
  get() {
    return get.call(this);
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onerror event using background: url()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287474/onerror-event-using-background-url)

Comment: @Justinas Unfortunately no, I have no control over these things, HTML elements, sources, styles, etc are added dynamically by third-party library.

Comment: Well, maybe you can just place images where it should be?

Comment: @Justinas For that I'd need to find out if `url()` error occured and where (in DOM) it occured. Like I said, I have no control over HTML nor CSS, I have to "clean up after".

Comment: Kindly see the reference website, i hope its useul it http://web.archive.org/web/20121119020227/http://lucassmith.name/pub/imgload.html

Comment: @Solo, do you know which elements to check? Or can the background be on any element on the page?

Comment: @rid It seems to be mostly on `div's` but yeah, I'd require a more flexible solution.

Comment: @Solo, can you also do this on the server, or does it have to be on the client?

Comment: @rid Has to be on client, I need to clean up after third-party code I have no control over.

Comment: @rid I wonder if it's possible to manually fill the image pixels without altering the `src`, because I have the `img` element in setter as `this` and I also have image data as blob.

Comment: @Solo, oh, wait, you have the `Image` instance. You can do a lot with that. But how did you get it? Do you go through all elements in the page?

Comment: @rid Look at the example `src` setter code, apparently CSS `url` creates an Image instance. I don't mind hacks like this as long as I get it to work, hacking Image is not an issue anyway because all this code runs in iframe and doesn't affect top window.

Comment: @rid I should add that I found out that Image instance in setter is not to final one being used, not sure what's the browser logic here.

Answer (score 0):

Service Workers can be used to intercept all the network calls in the browser.

You have to register the service worker like:

```
const registerServiceWorker = async () => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    try {
      const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(
        '/sw-test/sw.js',
        {
          scope: '/sw-test/',
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Registration failed with ${error}`);
    }
  }
};

registerServiceWorker();
```

And have the service worker `/sw-test/sw.js` look like:

```
const customFetch = async ({ request }) => {
  try {
    const responseFromNetwork = await fetch(request);
    // ADD FALLBACK HERE
    return responseFromNetwork;
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response('Network error happened', {
      status: 408,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
    });
  }
};

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const response = customFetch({
    request: event.request,
  });
  event.respondWith(response);
});
```