# Onerror attribute of background image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, event-listener

**HTML**

```html
<body>
    <form class="ipform">
        <label>CAM IP :</label>
        <input type="url" id="ip_cam">
        <input type="button" id="connectBtn" onclick="getIp()" value="CONNECT">
    </form>
    
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #1f1f29;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606851361385-9a2ead6ce3ab?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=751&q=80");  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

**JS**

```js
function getIp() {
  var x = "url('";
  var y = document.getElementById("ip_cam").value;
  var z = "')";
  var xyz = x + y + z; //"url('" get from y "')
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = xyz;
}
```

Inserting **url** of an image in the **input box**, the background image **changes.**
Now, for a **invalid link** how to set a default **background-image**
background-image have to use as CSS property not as div in html 
Randomly tried with these code below.But **Nothing happened**.I'm not so familiar with JavaScript **Can you please help..**

```
// function myFunction() {
//   document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/error3.gif')"
// }
// if(   document.body.style.backgroundImage.onerror = null )

// {
//   myFunction();
// }
// document.body.style.backgroundImage.addEventListener("error", myFunction);
```

Comment: You can use an Image() object and use the onload, onerror events to check if its valid.

Comment: look it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287474/onerror-event-using-background-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add the second url to background-image attribute, if the first one not loaded then the second one will load.

```
function getIp() {
  var x = "url('";
  var y = document.getElementById("ip_cam").value;
  var z = "'), url(assets/error3.gif)"; //added here with comma
  var xyz = x + y + z; 
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = xyz;
}
```