# Fallback Backgrounds when Image is missing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a fallback Background only if the Image that is supposed to be the Background is missing.

This is what I got:
`background: url(\'img/items/image.png\') , url(\'img/items/fallback.png\')`

But in this case both backgrounds are shown at the same time.
Don´t know why.

Comment: That's the way `background-image` is supposed to work. You probably will have to test for the image availability with JavaScript and deal with the results.

Comment: but this Thread says it should work like I want it to.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287474/onerror-event-using-background-url

Comment: that's not a fallback but two background layers on the top of each other

Comment: @LucasTea read again that thread, it's not saying what you are saying

Comment: so it works but not with trancparent Backgrounds right ?

Comment: What about using img src attribute, not css background?

Comment: Why the escapes `\'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can notice from the comments under your post, there is no such thing as a fallback but you always can find a way to solve the problem. Also keep in mind that sometimes when you come up with an unusual solution there is always be a price: performance, readability, etc.

For your situation I can suggest some ideas how you can solve that:

1. Use two images (those mustn't be transparent)

   `background-image: url("defaultImage.png"), url("backupImage.png"); background-position: 0 0, 0 0; background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;`
2. Use two nested HTML elements,  for instance. Styling them and add background-image for both.
3. In css add pseudo elements through `:before{content:" "; background:url(backup.png); display: block; position:absolute;}`